# Truncating a number using numeric format strings

Tags: .net, string-formatting, rounding

Is it possible to truncate a number using [numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) in .NET? Currently I am using `N0` for a `double` but this rounds the value. Due to a library restriction I must use a format string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this is not doable because:

- `"D"` [is only supported for integral types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#DFormatString)
- `"N"` [rounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#NFormatString)
- `"0"` [rounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#Specifier0)
- `"#"` [rounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierD)